# FormData not being properly sent from react to express server. req.body is empty

Tags: reactjs, express, form-data

I am sending form data from my react application over to a localhost express server. I've made sure that the formData I am about to sent is populated on the client side, but for some reason the req.body is always empty object on the server side. I tried using header to transfer some data to check if req was being sent, and yes I can access data from header of req on server side. It's just the body which is empty.
Below is the client side code to send request

```
const handleRegister = async (
  setDisabled: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>,
  values: InitialValues,
  pictureFile: File,
  resetForm: (
    nextState?: Partial<FormikState<InitialValues>> | undefined
  ) => void,
  uri: string
) => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  Object.keys(values).map((key) => {
    if (key === "confirm_password") return;
    formData.append(key, values[key]);
  });

  formData.append("picture", pictureFile);
  formData.append("picturePath", pictureFile.name);
  const rawData = await fetch(`${uri}/auth/register`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      email: values.email,
    },
    body: formData,
  });

  const jsonData = await rawData.json();
  // Always empty
  console.log(jsonData);
};
```

I am using formik and again, the formData is populated properly I've made sure of that.

And below is my server side code.

```
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import morgan from "morgan";
import helmet from "helmet";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import checkRouter from "./routes/checkRouter";
import authRouter from "./routes/authRouter";
import { register } from "./controllers/auth";
import checkExistingUser from "./middlewares/checkExistingUser";
import getRandomMiliseconds from "./utils/getRandomMiliseconds";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
dotenv.config();

app.use("/assets", express.static("public"));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const randomizedNumber = getRandomMiliseconds();
    cb(null, req.body.email + "-" + file.originalname + "-" + randomizedNumber);
  },
});

const uploadMiddleWare = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use("/check", checkRouter);
app.use("/auth", authRouter);

// app.post(
//   "/auth/register",
//   checkExistingUser,
//   // uploadMiddleWare.single("picture"),
//   register
// );

// In here the req.body is always empty.
app.post("/auth/register", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).json(req.body);
});

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/SweeterDB").then(() => {
  app.listen(3001, async () => {
    console.log("Server started, listening at port 3001");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the uploadMiddleWare before the routes that need to access the request body:

```
// ...
app.use(uploadMiddleWare.single("picture"));
app.use("/check", checkRouter);
app.use("/auth", authRouter);
// ...
```

Or You can Update the register route to use the uploadMiddleWare.single middleware for the picture field:

```
app.post("/auth/register", uploadMiddleWare.single("picture"), checkExistingUser, register);
```

By placing the uploadMiddleWare before the /auth/register route, you allow multer to handle the FormData and populate the req.body with the non-file fields. The checkExistingUser and register middleware should now be able to access the data from the req.body.

Comment: So what would I do if I don't want the image to be saved if email already exists?

Comment: Just ignore the image and use the data whatever you want to save

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue lies in the way you are handling the multipart/form-data in your Express server. When you use [bodyParser.json()](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#:%7E:text=bodyParser.,of%20gzip%20and%20deflate%20encodings.) middleware, it only parses JSON data in the request body, not form data. To handle multipart/form-data, you should use the multer middleware to parse the form data and make it available in req.body.

Install the multer package if you haven't already:

```
npm install multer
```

Here how you can modify your server-side code to use multer properly:

```
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import morgan from "morgan";
import helmet from "helmet";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import checkRouter from "./routes/checkRouter";
import authRouter from "./routes/authRouter";
import { register } from "./controllers/auth";
import checkExistingUser from "./middlewares/checkExistingUser";
import getRandomMiliseconds from "./utils/getRandomMiliseconds";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
dotenv.config();

app.use("/assets", express.static("public"));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const randomizedNumber = getRandomMiliseconds();
    cb(null, req.body.email + "-" + file.originalname + "-" + randomizedNumber);
  },
});

const uploadMiddleWare = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use("/check", checkRouter);
app.use("/auth", authRouter);

app.post(
  "/auth/register",
  checkExistingUser,
  uploadMiddleWare.single("picture"), // Use multer middleware to handle form data
  register
);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/SweeterDB").then(() => {
  app.listen(3001, async () => {
    console.log("Server started, listening at port 3001");
  });
});
```

With this modification, multer will properly handle the multipart/form-data, and you will be able to access req.body as expected in the register function and other route handlers.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I understand why it didn't work as well.